# How to show user their submitted form on different page? PHP SQL PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I am trying to make an adoption form where the user can see the form submitted.

In the navbar there is a an account page. When you click the account page, I want it listing all the requests submitted by the user.

only want to view the user account information but I get everyone's information in the request table. I think its the line `SELECT * FROM request` that needs to change but I don't know what too. I don't know what comes after WHERE.

I want the user that has logged in to be able to see the listed requests rather than seeing all requests made by every user which is what i get currently.

SQL Database

```
---login details---
CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(250) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

---adoption Request---

CREATE TABLE `request` (
 `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `fullname` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `email` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
 `address` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
 `postcode` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
 `present` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
 `category` enum('Snake','Rabbit', 'Hamster', 'Dog', 'Kitten') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Snake',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
userId INT NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Account Listing Code

```
  <div class="wrapper row3">
    <main class="hoc container clear">
      <!-- main body -->
      <div class="sectiontitle">
        <h6 class="heading">Account Information</h6>
        <p>Adoption Request Form</p>
      </div>
        <?php
        include("connectdb.php");
        ?>
        <table cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="10">
        <tr><th>fullname</th> <th >email</th><th >address</th> <th >postcode</th><th >present</th><th >category</tr></tr>
          <?php
            try{
            // Run a SQL query
                $sqlstr = "SELECT * FROM request";
                $rows=$db->query($sqlstr);
            //loop through all the returned records and display them in a table
                foreach ($rows as $row) {
                    echo  "<tr><td >" . $row['fullname'] . "</td><td >" . $row['email'] . "</td><td >" . $row['address'];
                    echo "</td><td >" . $row['postcode'] . "</td><td >" . $row['present'] . "<tr><td >" . $row['category']."</td></tr>\n";
                }

                echo "</table> <br>";
            } catch (PDOException $ex){
                //this catches the exception when the query is thrown
                echo "Sorry, a database error occurred when querying the vehicle records. Please try again.<br> ";
                echo "Error details:". $ex->getMessage();
            }

          ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: If you want to view a specific request, it would be `WHERE id = :id` and the you'd put the ID of the record you want in the parameters when you execute it. (make sure you're using prepared statements for this, not just ->query). As for where the ID value actually comes from - it would make sense to put it on the querystring when navigating to this page - e.g. `userAccount.php?id=123`, then your PHP code can retrieve it with as `$id = $_GET["id"];`.

Comment: P.S. It's strange you call your page userAccount when actually it lists requests, not accounts?

Comment: Also you said `I want the user that has logged in to only see their own details.` ...you mean only requests that they have submitted? The main problem with that is that your `requests` table doesn't record which user submitted them. You need a `userid` field in there which is a foreign key back to the `accounts` table, and you need to put the current user's ID into that field whenever you are inserting a request record. (I would guess you store the current user's ID in the Session in PHP?). Once you've got that, the query would be something like `SELECT * FROM request WHERE userid = :uid`

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your help. I am confused on how to add a prepared statement into my current code. I didn't know how to phrase the question, I'll be honest but you phrased it for me. How do I list the adoption requests  on a separate page? I will add the code of prepared statement in the edit to try to act on what you said

Comment: `I am confused on how to add a prepared statement into my current code`...then take a tutorial on prepared statements. You need to replace a little of your current code with the prepared statement code. https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for locating the problem. where do i put the foreign key ? In the sql. Sorry I am new to this. I've only ever done front end web development.

Comment: `How do I list the adoption requests on a separate page`...on a separate page from what? From this one? This page you've given us the code for shows adoption requests already. Are you saying you want this page to show the `accounts` details and a separate page to show the `requests` details? It's a bit unclear.

Comment: @ADyson I'll edit my question, one second.

Comment: `where do i put the foreign key`...again, this is a common task, so find a tutorial such as https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-foreign-key/ to understand the concepts and get examples, and then you can apply that to what you need in your own code.

Comment: @ADyson updated my code where userId is the foreign key. The userId in accounts is the foreign key column that refers to the userId column in the request table.

Comment: Thanks but you've somewhat misunderstood the concept I think. 1) you've already got `id` in accounts, you don't need another ID there. 2) userid in the requests table is not the primary key and must be not automatically generated. You need to be able to enter the same user ID into multiple rows of that table, remember! You're implementing a one-to-many relationship, where one account can be associated with many requests. 3) `userid` in requests needs to reference the already-existing `id` field in accounts as the foreign key. You haven't actually defined the key constraint at all yet...

Comment: @ADyson Previously, I changed the userId in accounts back to ```PRIMARY KEY (`id`)``` so now for userId in request ```PRIMARY KEY (`id`)```. I changed the id to ````id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,``` so it won't be automatically generated. Code edit above. I am sorry for disturbing you. I am now going to work on point 3 you made

Comment: But now you've removed userID from requests...you still need that, it just mustn't be a primary key or auto-increment, it should just be a simple non-null integer field. once you create that you can set up the foreign key constraint sucessfully.

Comment: @ADyson so you mean userId INT NOT NULL for request.

Comment: @ADyson ok that makes sense. I'm doing the prepared statement currently but I just wanted the database side to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Read up on entity-relationship data modeling. Seriously. Go and do it.

Your *entities* (tables) are, I believe,

- `account` with one row per human user
- `critter` with one row per creature to be adopted
- `request` with one row per adoption request

Each of these tables contains attributes of the entity. `account.email` and `account.firstname` for example.  `critter.species` and `critter.is_adopted_yet` for example.

Each table will have an autoincrementing primary key `account_id`, `critter_id`, `request_id`.

`request` will contain a `critter_id` and an `account_id` as well as the attributes describing the request. That is, each row of `request` represents a *relationship* between an `account` and a `critter`.

Then, when looking for information about a single account's requests, you'll do something like this.

```
 SELECT request.account_id, critter.*
   FROM request
   JOIN critter ON request.critter_id = critter.critter_id
  WHERE request.account_id = ?
```

Using a `WHERE` filter to pull out just the account you want.

Comment: Yes...although it may be that the request is to adopt _some creature_ of the type specified, rather than a specific individual animal. e.g. request to adopt "a snake" rather than "the snake called bobby". We don't know. So while the critter table is a good idea in theory, it might also require a critterType table. Then later on the requestor might be allocated/offered a specific individual animal. Depends how the adoption process actually works.

Comment: Understood.  That's why you need to develop your own entity-relationship design. I was guessing. CritterType is a good entity.

Comment: I'm not the OP so I won't be developing that. But my point was that the question is more about the concepts and mechanics of defining the relationship between the existing tables than it is about bigger alterations to the structure of the schema